# Excel: What's the best way to get the value of a Relative Row but from a Fixed Column?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

The following formula will always return the value of the 4th column (D) of the next row.

```
=INDIRECT("R[1]C[" & 4-COLUMN() & "]",FALSE)
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar, but less wordy and easier to read (IMHO), is the A1 style of addressing:

```
=INDIRECT("$D" & ROW()+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting a '$' character in front of a column letter or row number will lock it down when you copy and paste.

Eg:

```
$C$17
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by better :-)

If you mean shorter/simpler and A1 style, then shoover's answer is fine:

`=INDIRECT("$D"&ROW()+1)`

If you prefer R1C1 style (easier to read IMHO ;-) ) then an even shorter/simpler/faster solution is:

`=INDIRECT("R[1]C4",)`

However, if you're after the fastest solution, or just simply prefer a non-volatile one, then a Named Formula is the way to go:

- Define a Name, say `Col4Down1`, and set its value to:

  `=INDEX(!$D:$D,ROW()+1)`
- Place the following formula in a cell to get the desired result:

  `=Col4Down1`

This works because of a little known quirk when using the bang operator `!` in a Named Formula. When you don't specify a sheetname, `!$D:$D` always refers to the fourth column *irrespective of column deletions/insertions*. Think of it as absolute-absolute addressing.

Finally, Lance Roberts' answer, whilst being non-volatile, suffers from a couple of problems. As he mentions, it will only work in certain, predetermined, rows. Secondly, insertion/deletion of any columns from A-D, or of any rows above, will break it. Modifying it to fix these leads to the following (if entered into cell B2):

`=INDEX(B:B:2:2,ROW()+1,4)`

or if you prefer R1C1 style and have set your spreadsheet to use this style:

`=INDEX(R:C,ROW()+1,4)`

Comment: +1 on the `!$D:$D` quirk - I wasn't aware of that. Pity it only works in defined names but not in regular formulas.

Comment: @Peter - thanks for the vote. Yeah, the equivalent for regular formulae is `INDEX(G:G:6:6,1,4):INDEX(G:G:6:6,ROWS(G:G),4)` (entered in G6), or, if you switch on R1C1 style addressing, the slightly simpler and easier to use `INDEX(R:C,1,4):INDEX(R:C,ROWS(C),4)`.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you know the range:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$4, ROW()+1, 4)
```